# axWindowsMediaPlayer event after media stopped playing

Tags: c#, winforms, video, slideshow, axwindowsmediaplayer

I imported a `axWindowsMediaPlayer` control to my form to play a sequence of pictures and/or small videos.

Now I want the user to adjust the slide show to his own needs, so he should be able to select the "showtime" of each picture and just play the video's length.

I tried to apply a timer to the form, and change the `axWindowsMediaPlayer` URL every "x" amount of seconds. This works perfectly for pictures, but videos now have an extra blank screen or footage cut off (depends on the time of the video compared to the "x" amount of seconds).

I want to to use an event, which will trigger when the media has stopped playing(so it wont cut off video's), but when I searched trough the `axWindowsMediaPlayer` event's list, I only found `onMediaChanged`. This event is kinda strange, it triggers a few times on the beginning of a video and at the end...

Is there anyway I can solve this? Maby using something different than the `axWindowsMediaPlayer`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after google'ing for hours. If anyone wants to know how to acces the `axWindowsMediaPlayer`'s duration:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration
```

It's a property (get and set) so this is all I needed.